# How to run electron inside an alpine docker image with Testcafe?

Tags: docker, testing, electron, testcafe, alpine-linux

I'm trying to run my e2e Tests for an electron app with [Testcafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/) on gitlab inside a docker image.

Therefor i use a docker [image from Testcafe](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile) which i only extend by installing `yarn`.

The gitlab script just builds my e2e Tests (which succeeds), but electron does not come up and the pipeline stops with this error:

```
$ /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh electron:./ci ./test/e2e/ --screenshots takeOnFails=true
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
Error: spawn /builds/myFancyProject/node_modules/electron/dist/electron ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Any suggestion to solve this error?

This is my simple docker file:

```
FROM testcafe/testcafe

USER root

RUN apk add --update yarn
```

Comment: and whats in your pipeline script?

Comment: just `yarn` calls which work in a plain ubuntu image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official TestCafe Docker image uses Alpine as a base image. Electron doesn't support Alpine right now: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9662#issuecomment-420480342.
We have plans to offer more official images, including Ubuntu-based ones, but I cannot give you any ETA as to when they will be available: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3100

Currently, you can use [circleci/node:latest-browsers](https://hub.docker.com/r/circleci/node/tags?page=1&name=latest) and install TestCafe with `npm` if you want to use Electron with TestCafe and Docker.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I tried this before and electron starts as expected, but the `resizeWindow` call fails (only inside the docker container). My workaround was to test the alpine image with electron.

Comment: Created a [new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63520749/how-to-use-resizewindow-with-docker-and-electron-in-testcafe) for the original `resizeWindow` issue.