# How to use 'resizeWindow' with docker and electron in Testcafe?

Tags: docker, testing, electron, resize, testcafe

I have an issue using `resizeWindow` from [Testcafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/) inside a docker container while testing an electron app with gitlab.

**Note**: On local setup (linux) all tests work as expected, but inside the docker container `resizeWindow` does not seem to work. Other tests inside the container work as well.

Maybe i'm missing any configuration for `xvfb` or should i use `fluxbox`?

Any suggestion how to solve this?

---

## Test error with docker:

```
$ yarn test-e2e-ci
yarn run v1.22.4
$ node -r @babel/register ./internals/scripts/CheckBuildsExist.js && cross-env NODE_ENV=test testcafe electron:./ci ./test/e2e/DockerTest.e2e.ts --screenshots takeOnFails=true
 Running tests in:
 - Electron 9.0.4 / Linux 0.0
 Docker execution
 ✖ `ResizeWindow` works as expected 
   1) AssertionError: expected 1024 to deeply equal 100
      Browser: Electron 9.0.4 / Linux 0.0
          8 |
          9 |test('`ResizeWindow` works as expected ', async t => {
         10 |  await t.resizeWindow(100, 100);
         11 |  const innerWidth = await t.eval(() => window.innerWidth);
         12 |  const innerHeight = await t.eval(() => window.innerHeight);
       > 13 |  await t.expect(innerWidth).eql(100);
         14 |  await t.expect(innerHeight).eql(100);
         15 |});
         16 |
         at <anonymous>
      (/builds/myFancyProject/test/e2e/DockerTest.e2e.ts:13:30)
         at fulfilled
      (/builds/myFancyProject/test/e2e/DockerTest.e2e.ts:5:58)
 1/1 failed (8s)
```

---

## Warnings:

```
 Warnings (3):
 --
  Was unable to resize the window due to an error.
  The
  /builds/myFancyProject/node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/bin/linux/glibc-64/resize
  process failed with the null exit code.
 --
```

---

## Used Test setup:

#### ResizeWindow Testcafe test

```
test('`ResizeWindow` works as expected ', async t => {
  await t.resizeWindow(100, 100);
  const innerWidth = await t.eval(() => window.innerWidth);
  const innerHeight = await t.eval(() => window.innerHeight);
  await t.expect(innerWidth).eql(100);
  await t.expect(innerHeight).eql(100);
});
```

#### Start up inside gitlab yml

`- xvfb-run --server-num=99 --server-args='-ac -screen 0 1024x768x16' yarn test-e2e-ci`

#### package.json

`"test-e2e-ci": "node -r @babel/register ./internals/scripts/CheckBuildsExist.js && cross-env NODE_ENV=test testcafe electron:./ci ./test/e2e/ --screenshots takeOnFails=true",`

#### ./ci/.testcafe-electron-rc

```
{
  "mainWindowUrl": "../app/app.html",
  "appPath": "../app",
  "appArgs": "--no-sandbox"
}
```

#### Tested docker images:

`circleci/node:latest-browsers`

```
FROM node:lts-stretch

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y xvfb \
    libnotify4 \
    libgconf2-4 \
    libnss3 \
    libxtst-dev \
    libc6 \
    libstdc++6 \
    libgcc1 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libasound2 \
    libxrender1 \
    libxss1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correctly install and setup the `fluxbox` tool.
See an example in TestCafe docker related files:

- https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile
- https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/docker/testcafe-docker.sh

Comment: Indeed `Xvfb`, display setting and `fluxbox >/dev/null 2>&1 &` did the trick, thx.